# Modify iTunes library from a script

Tags: itunes, applescript, automator, playlist, swift

In my project, I have a bunch of music tracks in a directory of my computer.

I want to add them to my iTunes library in an automated way. I also want to group them in playlists depending on the folder they were in, so just moving them in the Library folder won't do it for me.

Also, I can't use the AppleMusic API (I don't really want to buy an Apple developer licence for a small personal project.)

I thought about a bunch of possible ways to do that, but I'm not aware enough to know what could work/would be less tricky to implement :

- use a Swift script using iTunesLibrary module
- modify iTunes database to create playlists and link songs
- use Automator, AppleScript or other software

I don't know how to code with Swift, manipulate iTunes' database or what Automator can be used for. Anyone with experience that could guide me would be greatly thanked.

*Edit: some more precisions*

Comment: I'd start at https://dougscripts.com/itunes/index.php - thousands of scripts for iTunes

Comment: Hi @simon!  What is the repetitive task here?

Comment: @Tetsujin Woah ! This looks promising, thanks !

Comment: @ankii, the thing is that the folder where I group those songs could be modified by another script regularly, so I want the treatment to be automated instead of manually drag and drop the tracks each time.

Comment: one thing that can make it super easy, if you copy the tracks folder in Finder to iTunes Music folder in Finder, would iTunes register the update ? (@Tetsujin .575 thousand to be exact ;p  )

Comment: @ankii Yup, they would be added to the Library but I precisely want to place them in a playlist with the name of their folder. That can't be done by just moving files in the iTunes Music folder